# Term for neurotic covert behavior

Tags: neuroticism

[This online article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/theory-knowledge/201211/when-are-you-neurotic) defines neurotic habits as:

> ...automatic or ritualized patterns of overt behavior that people engage in to alleviate anxiety and provide a sense of familiar security.

Is there a term for patterns of **covert** behavior in the same context?